# MvvmCross iOS: How to bind MapView Annotation to jump to another view?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

How can I bind the MapView's annotation to switch to different view when it's callout accessory button is clicked? How do I implement the annotation's CalloutAccessoryControlTapped method?

Or what is the best way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
[Register("MapView")]
public class MapView : MvxViewController
{

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        Title = "Map";
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var mapView = new MKMapView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 20 - 44))
            {
                MapType = MKMapType.Standard,
                ZoomEnabled = true,
                ScrollEnabled = true,
                Delegate = new MapDelegate(),
            };
        View.AddSubview(mapView);

        var center = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(ViewModel.CurrentLat, ViewModel.CurrentLong);
        var span = new MKCoordinateSpan(5.0, 5.0);
        var region = new MKCoordinateRegion(center, span);
        mapView.SetRegion(region, true);

        mapView.AddAnnotation(CreateNewAnnotation(ViewModel.CurrentLat, ViewModel.CurrentLong, "You are here"));

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MapView, MapViewModel>();
        set.Bind(mapView).For(???).To(vm => vm.showDetailCommand); // how can I bind to the map annotation and switch to other view when user click it?
        set.Apply();
    }

    protected class MapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
    {
        public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject annotation)
        {
            var pinId = "locationPinId";
            var pinView = (LocationAnnotationView)mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(pinId) ??
                          new LocationAnnotationView
                    {
                        Annotation = annotation,
                        RestorationIdentifier = pinId,
                        Image = UIImage.FromBundle("images/map_pointer_icon_small.png"),
                    };

                var buttonView = new UIButton(new RectangleF(0, 0, 27, 27));
                buttonView.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("images/blue_arrow.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
                buttonView.Tag = 88888;
                pinView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = buttonView;

            return pinView;
        }

        public override void CalloutAccessoryControlTapped(MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView view, UIControl control)
        {
            // how can I bind this method, so when the user click on the annotation it can switch to other view?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in lots of ways.

Given that you are already using fixed non-binding (non-updating) single item display, then the easiest approach is probably for you to just extend your Annotation so that it is created with an `ICommand` as well as the lat, lng and label:

```
CreateNewAnnotation(
  ViewModel.CurrentLat, 
  ViewModel.CurrentLong, 
  ViewModel.ShowDetailCommand, 
  "You are here")
```

Once this is done, then the `ICommand`:

- can then easily be invoked from your call-out or from your buttonView's `TouchUpInside` or from your `CalloutAccessoryControlTapped` handler.
- can be implemented inside `ShowDetailCommand` as a navigation command - see N=5 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/ for examples of navigations.

If you do want a much more dynamic annotation - with true data-binding, then you would need to start looking at adding data-binding to your custom Annotation class, to your custom AnnotationView and perhaps also to your custom MapViewDelegate - this would be similar to the way data-binding is added to a UIView - see [MvxView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxView.cs) - but is probably *overkill* for your current example.