# How to bind Map/Image in a List with Click event?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to bind map with a field and its click event as well, which will take it to a MvxCommand and show some MapViewModel.

```
[Register("HoursEntryCell")]
public class HoursEntryCell : MvxTableViewCell
{        
    public HoursEntryCell()            
    {
        CreateLayout();
        InitializeBindings();
    }

    public HoursEntryCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        CreateLayout();
        InitializeBindings();
    }

    private UILabel hours;
    private UIImageView imageView;
    private UILabel jobName;
    private MKMapView location;

    private void CreateLayout()
    {
        jobName = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 10, 100, 30));
        jobName.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        jobName.Lines = 0;
        jobName.Font = jobName.Font.WithSize(16);

        imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("pencil.png"));
        imageView.Frame = new RectangleF(270, 10,imageView.Image.CGImage.Width, imageView.Image.CGImage.Height);

        Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        location = new MKMapView(new RectangleF(15, 40, 280, 160));
        location.AddAnnotation(new MKPointAnnotation()
        {
            Title = "My Loc",
            Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(23.0092509, 72.5061084)
        });
        location.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

       salaryLable.Text = "Salary";
       hours = new UILabel(new RectangleF(200,200,50,50));
       ContentView.AddSubviews(jobName, location, hours,salaryLable, imageView);
    }

    private void InitializeBindings()
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HoursEntryCell, ListViewModel>();
            set.Bind(location).To(vm => vm.MyLocation);
            set.Bind(hours).To(vm => vm.Salary);
            set.Bind(jobName).To(vm => vm.EmployeeName);

            set.Apply();
        }); 
    }
}
```

}

I want to achieve something like set.Bind(location).To(vm => vm.GoNextCommand); along with the map (set.Bind(location).To(vm => vm.MyLocation);)

Or How can I bind simple image button click event to a MvxCommand from the list?

How can I go for it?
Need Help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to do a combination of things to get this to work properly...

1.) Do your binding from the view that has your list view.  In the example above how does the cell actually get access to your view model?  Look at the example here:  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DailyDilbert/DailyDilbert.Touch/Views/ListView.cs#L16

2.) you'll need to probably create custom bindings to handle the map view or it might be similar to this example from Stuart:  [MvvmCross iOS: How to bind MapView Annotation to jump to another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756846/mvvmcross-ios-how-to-bind-mapview-annotation-to-jump-to-another-view)